# Efficient Gaussian mixture evaluation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, gmm

I'd like to (efficiently) evaluate a Gaussian mixture model (GMM) over an `(n,d)` list of datapoints, given the GMM parameters ($\pi_k, \mu_k, \Sigma_k$).  I can't find a way to do this using standard `sklearn` or `scipy` packages.

EDIT: assume there is `n` datapoints, dimension `d` so `(n,d)`, and GMM has `k` components, so for example the covariance matrix of the k-th component, \Sigma_k, is `(d,d)`, and altogether \Sigma is `(k,d,d)`.

For example, if you first *fit* a GMM in sklearn, you can call `score_samples`, but this only works if I'm fitting to data.  Or, in `scipy` you can run a for-loop over `multivariate_normal.pdf` with each set of parameters, and do a weighted sum/dot product, but this is slow.  Checking the source code of either was not illuminating (for me).

I'm currently hacking something together with n-d arrays and tensor dot products .. oy .. hoping someone has a better way?

Comment: Is each $\Sigma_k$ a d-by-d covariance matrix?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, thanks, edited for clarity